# How to resolve in gradle transitive dependencies between services?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am working in intellij, using spring boot and gradle.

I have a service that is using two other libraries and it seems I run into some problems with transitive dependencies.

The version of spring boot has updated in this service from 2.1.2 to 2.1.4 and that made the service not working anymore.

I am able to clean build this project in gradle just fine, but once I start it, at runtime I get...Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26.

I manually updated the slf4j dependency in the libraries from 1.7.25 to 1.7.26 as asked, but with little success.

If I run dependecies on this service I get what I think it is, to change the version to the right one:

```
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
```

but that might be a problem bcz that's a transitive dep of the logback classic. For this package on mvn I find that the slf4j api has been updated: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3.

That was just one of them, if I search for all -> in the terminal I get 498 mathces, so it might be a problem to manually change all of them.

I've tried to delete .gradle folder from all projects, clean build, install but w/ no success.

Comment: `Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26.` : this does not look like a Java runtime exception, but more an exception thrown by Gradle during dependencies resolution phase : when exactly do you get this error? (which command)

Comment: when I try to run the spring boot configuration

Comment: srry for not being more specific. i don't get any errors when I run gradle commands. The gradle cmd: clean build runs just fine. When I try to start the service I get the error mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was some caching behind this. Clearing intelli cache, File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... did the trick